# What is the present perfect form of verb can?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

For example, I want to say that I have done some task (in sense, that I was able to do it). It resembles a form like this, but I am not sure that it is correct:

> Yes, I could have (do something)

In other words, I want to say "Yes, I can" in present perfect tense.

Comment: *Yes, I have been able to*?

Comment: Can I do not specify type of action? for example: 

Have you solved task? Yes, I have been able.

Comment: The modal verbs like "can" do not have past participles, so they are unable to form the perfect tense. The perfect requires the perfect auxiliary "have" + past participle.

Comment: @BillJ, Yes, I know that. But I want to find not modal verb, which can represent my intention. It seems like that usage verb be is solution (as comment above)

Comment: As a workaround, you could say "Yes, I've been able to do x"

Comment: Yes, I think it is what I search

Comment: You wouldn't normally use the perfect form *I have been able to do X* unless the end result of doing it had particular relevance to the time of speaking. For most contexts it's more likely you'd just say *I **was** able to do it*. We tend not to say *I **could** do it* with this exact sense, because it drags in unwanted ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can* is a modal, so it never really works by itself, even though it has *could* which is something like a "past tense" form.

Any time you see it in a sentence by itself there is really another verb following it that was omitted for brevity/conversational elision.

> Can you teach English.  Yes I can {teach English}.

So you have to use *be able* if you want to express that meaning of *can* in the perfect tense.

> I've been able to teach English since last year.